# Network Error Axios trying to get data from localhost

Tags: php, react-native, axios

I'm using XAMPP for API

I have this error in console:

```
Network Error
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:80:22 in handleError
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

With the simple code:

```
const apiAsyncTest = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://127.0.0.1/api/api.php');
            console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    apiAsyncTest();
```

Already checked the internet of the android emulator, I changed the "127.0.0.1" to "localhost" https to http, but nothing works

My page api code contains simple code too:

```
<?php 
echo 'test';
```

But I tried it on another website and I got it successfully

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I changed "localhost" to my IPV4 and work successfully